# Shell get closed right after it opened in ssh

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

So I in a middle of a challenge (works on ssh) and inside the challenge there is a function calling `system("/bin/sh");` and what I need to do is to keep it open (to write my own stuff there in order to use permissions) but what actually does is that it even not opening a # or a $ to show that I opened a shell with a root permissions there. Somebody could tell why the shell does it? I don't know, maybe it because the ssh or something. thanks!

Comment: It will not print a `#` or `$` if stdin is not a terminal. If stdin is additionally closed or eof, it will also exit immediately.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. You should describe your setup more thoroughly. Include any relevant source code and say what host it's running on (the host you're trying to connect from, or the host you're trying to connect to).